# Remove empty columns from a DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, collections, datatable

I want to remove all empty columns from a DataTable. I created a list of all columns that consist of only empty rows, and then delete them.

It doesn't work because of a `System.InvalidOperationException`. The exception claims I try to edit the collection that I enumerate, something I don't understand since I think I copied that collection.

```
private DataTable data;

public void removeEmptyColoums()
{
// Get all empty coloums
  IEnumerable<DataColumn> queriableColumms = data.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().AsQueryable();
  var toBeRemoved = from DataColumn column in queriableColumms
                    where data.AsEnumerable().All(row => row.IsNull(column))
                    select column;
  // Delete them
  foreach(DataColumn column in toBeRemoved)  // Exception thrown here
  {
    data.Columns.Remove(column);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure about the. `AsQueryable` and `.Cast` calls either.

Comment: When you remove items fro a list you have to start at last item and work towards beginning.  For example if you have rows 1,2,3 and you remove row 2 then row 3 becomes 2.  Well your exception was due to same issue.  Try following :   for(int i = toBeRemoved.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i-- )  
            {
                _data.Columns.Remove(toBeRemoved.Skip(i).First());
            }

Comment: `foreach(DataColumn column in toBeRemoved.ToArray()`

Comment: define it like an array `var[] toBeRemoved` and then perform iteration of `foreach` loop on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My humble guess:

As long as the list isn't finalized (with `ToList()` for example), you are indeed working on it, and never actually making a copy.

```
IEnumerable<DataColumn> queriableColumms = data.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().AsQueryable();
```

We see here that you use `data` to produce a `Queryable`, not an independent list.

```
var toBeRemoved = from DataColumn column in queriableColumms
                where data.AsEnumerable().All(row => row.IsNull(column))
                select column;
```

Here as well, you're using LinqToSQL, and not finalizing the list.

So when you call `toBeRemoved`, you call the query's result, thus are still using the original source, `data`.

Try using `toBeRemoved.ToList()`, and doing your loop on that.

---

Actually, I think the problem may lie somewhere else since you say your exception happens when you start your loop on `toBeRemoved` and not when you actually try to delete an item, but I'll edit later if this solution doesn't work.